# Storing array in the database column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this form in the view:

```
Your Name: <input type="name" name="name" id="name" ><br><br>
Your Contact No. <input type="contact" name="contact" id="contact" ><br><br>
Todays date:<mark>{{$mytime->format('Y-m-d, l')}}</mark><br><br>
<br><br>BOOK SEATS:<br>
@foreach($seats as $seat)
@if($seat->available=='1')
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="{{$seat->book}}" >{{$seat->book}}<br><br>
 @else
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="{{$seat->book}}" disabled>{{$seat->book}}<br><BR>
@endif
@endforeach
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Book</button>
</form>
```

this form redirects to this controller which inserts the name contact and the value of checkbox checked with loop. This way, if i check two values and submit the form, due to for loop two rows will be inserted with same `name` `contact` but with different `booked_seats` and `id`(i used id as auto increment). Is there any way of inserting the checked values into booked_seats with only one row. OR making the `id` same for any rows inserted(checked values) at the time.

```
 public function book(Request $request)
  {
    $name=$request->get('name');
    $contact=$request->get('contact');
    $check=$request->get('check');
    $totalcheckboxchecked=sizeof('$check'); 
for($i=0;$i<=$totalcheckboxchecked;$i++)
{
    if (array_key_exists($i,$check) )
{   
    $booked=$check[$i];
    $book=bus::insert(['name'=>$name,'contact'=>$contact, 'booked_seats'=>$booked, 'active'=>'1']);
    seats::where('book',$booked)->update(['available'=>'0']);

}
}
        return redirect('/bus')
            ->with('message','booked successfully!!!');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the checked values in database using serialize

```
$booked = serialize ($check);
```

Then you can save in database like this without using for loop

```
$book=bus::insert(['name'=>$name,'contact'=>$contact, 'booked_seats'=>$booked, 'active'=>'1']);
    seats::where('book',$booked)->update(['available'=>'0']);
```

To rretrieve the values use unserialize

```
unserialize($booked);
```

Here is the full code.

```
public function book(Request $request)
  {
    $name=$request->get('name');
    $contact=$request->get('contact');
    $check=$request->get('check');
    $checkarray = serialize($check);
    $totalcheckboxchecked=sizeof('$check'); 
for($i=0;$i<=$totalcheckboxchecked;$i++)
{
    if (array_key_exists($i,$check) )
{   
    $booked=$check[$i];

    seats::where('book',$booked)->update(['available'=>'0']);

}
$book=bus::insert(['name'=>$name,'contact'=>$contact, 'booked_seats'=>$checkarray, 'active'=>'1']);
}
        return redirect('/bus')
            ->with('message','booked successfully!!!');

}
```

Comment: this is good. but `a:2:{i:0;s:2:"B1";i:1;s:2:"B2"` is inserted in database, i want B1 and B2 to later compare these values. i wrote the update query `seats::where('book',$booked)->update(['available'=>'0']);`

Comment: separate the two queries. For update you can do what you were doing previously. At least it wont insert a new row.

Comment: I want to upadate if $booked  matches the value stored in `book` column (book column has values B1, B2, B3,...) previously B1, B2, B3... were inserted now `a:2:{i:0;s:2:"B1";i:1;s:2:"B2"`

Comment: you have to unserialize it. Update it with a foreach loop, create a new array and before storing to database serialize it again. hope i am clear.

Comment: the values to insert into `bus` table using checkbox are fetched from another table `seats`. now if the checked values equals to values stored in 'book' column of seats then i want to update the `available` column of `seats` table to zero. used `$update=unserialize($booked);
 seats::where('book',$update)->update(['available'=>'0']);` but failed.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal I have modified your function and posted. Please check if this works.